# In case cypress finds the path and is stuck with not.exist error

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I want to compare path Alert with ExpectedResult, but now the programer not check script in this part,  so I use not.exist to skip case that Path Alert is not found, but in case that path Alert is found, Cypress program still reads . not.exist, and I want it to run through it without getting this error.

> Timed out retrying after 4000ms:
> Expected `<li>` not to exist in the DOM, but it was continuously found.

```js
if (cy.get('.help-block > ul > li').should('not.exist')) {
            cy.get('.help-block > ul > li').should('not.exist').then((Path_Alert) => {
              console.log(Path_Alert)
              if (Path_Alert == null) {
                cy.log(data.rows[i].ExpectedResult)
                ErrorSuggestion = cy.log('Not Alert or Alert Not Match').as('ErrorSuggestion')
              }
            })
            cy.get('#swal2-title').should('be.visible').invoke('text').then((text) => {
              if (text == 'พบข้อผิดพลาด!' || text == 'การเพิ่มสำเร็จ!') {
                cy.log(text).as('Alert_Popup')
                if (text == 'พบข้อผิดพลาด!') {
                  result = 'Fail'
                  cy.log(result).as('Result')
                  cy.get('.swal2-confirm').click()
                } else if (text == 'การเพิ่มสำเร็จ!') {
                  cy.get('.swal2-confirm').click()
                }

              }
            })
          } else {
            if (cy.get('.help-block > ul > li').should('be.visible')) {
              cy.get('.help-block > ul > li').should('be.visible').then((Path_Alert) => {
                console.log(Path_Alert)
                if (expect(Path_Alert).equal(data.rows[i].ExpectedResult)) {
                  result = 'Pass'
                  cy.log(result).as('Result')
                }
              })
            }

            cy.get('#swal2-title').should('be.visible').invoke('text').then((text) => {
              if (text == 'พบข้อผิดพลาด!' || text == 'การเพิ่มสำเร็จ!') {
                cy.log(text).as('Alert_Popup')
                if (text == 'พบข้อผิดพลาด!') {
                  result = 'Fail'
                  cy.log(result).as('Result')
                  cy.get('.swal2-confirm').click()
                } else if (text == 'การเพิ่มสำเร็จ!') {
                  cy.get('.swal2-confirm').click()
                }

              }
            })
          }
```

Test image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check like this

```js
cy.get('.help-block').then($helpBlock =>
  const li = $helpBlock.find('ul').find('li)
  if (li.length === 0) {
    // not-exists part
  } else {
    // exists part
  }
})
```